# APP vs Application Name in Connection String

Tags: .net, connection-string

What's the differences between the `APP` attribute and `Application Name` attributes in the connection string? Is one just an alias to another one? I can't seem to find any documentations about it.

Also, can I put spaces in the value of the `Application Name`? e.g. `Application Name=foo bar;`

Comment: according to [this link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/use-application-name-sql-server) you can put space there

Answer (score 11):

The answer for your first question is yes, app is just an alias.  Documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring

As for your second question, the same documentation page says that the name can be up to 128 characters and says nothing about excluding spaces.  A quick test revealed that spaces are allowed.